# 2 switch to one - Similar but not the same

Tags: electrical, switch

I have  outside security lights on two separate switches.  I am remodeling and have removed a door and now only want one switch to control the security lights.

When disconnecting the one switch I think I opened the circuit and now the other will not operate the light.  I am wondering if I should connect the red and Black with a wire nut and cap the other black in order to close the circuit and have the one switch work.

[image]

Comment: How was it wired previously?

Answer (score 2):

The black wire going into the groups of black wires with the red wire nut is your feed. The solo black and red wires were your travelers to the other switch. Connect your feed to one of the travelers. Try your other switch. If the switch position is correct, toggle up is on, toggle down is off, you're good to go, cap the unused traveler. If not, then connect the feed to the other traveler and cap the unused one.

Put a blank box cover over the box without the switch. It has to remain accessible and can't be drywalled over.

Comment: It depends on how it was wired the colors may be different, if you took a photo of the wiring on the now removed switch the wire that went to the dark colored screw to one of the other 2 (not the bare copper ground) are the ones to connect.

Comment: @EdBeal It is the rules and not too much color choice.

Comment: @user263983 well I guess I would agree if you can show me where in code the common screw and travelers colors are identified. note we usually use black or red as the hot but some electricians like me use the white reidentified as code used to specify this for a switch leg.

Comment: @Ed,Beal what code are you asking? What country?

Comment: User263983. The national electric code same as the answer that that comment actually supports.

Comment: +1 with special emphasis for the last paragraph.